# Fscanf in C for storing data from file

Tags: c, scanf

Here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct element {
    int value;
    char activity;
};

typedef struct element element;

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    element a;

    while(feof(fp) == 0) {
        fscanf(fp, "%c %d", &a.activity, &a.value);

        printf("\n%d", a.value);
    }
}
```

now,it outputs me every integer on file two time..

Howcome i am getting this weird answer?

My structure is:

```
struct element {
    int value;
    char activity;
};

typedef struct element element;
```

and my input file is:

```
i 23
i 56
i 19
i 20
i 44
```

Comment: Please show your input file and the definition of your structure.

Comment: Where's the code that queries `a.activity` and reveals it to be 134514592?

Comment: @DanielWagner I am debuggin it, and that is when i see the value of a.activity to be 134514592.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `fscanf` pattern:

```
fscanf(fp, "%c,%d", &a.activity, &a.value);
```

Then at your file format:

```
i 23
i 56
i 19
i 20
i 44
```

I don't see any commas. Try a space instead, and be sure to take the newline into account:

```
fscanf(fp, "%c %d\n", &a.activity, &a.value);
```

Remember `fscanf` doesn't just read values in order, it respects the fixed characters surrounding the wildcards.

**Edit -- also important, pointed out by Keith in the comments:**

> *Note that using `\n` in the `fscanf` format string may be slightly
>   misleading. Any white-space character (including `\n`) matches zero or
>   more white-space characters. So adding the `\n` works for the given
>   input -- but it would also work if the input were all on one line
>   separated by spaces or tabs: `i 23 i 56 i 19 i 20 i 44`. If you really
>   want line-oriented input, use `fgets()` (not `gets()`) to read a line
>   at a time into a string, then `sscanf()` to parse the string. (All the
>   `*scanf()` functions have problems with numeric overflow, though.)*

Hope it helps!

(PS: oh, and I fixed your code formatting. Next time you post, take a second to make sure the code looks properly indented and stuff. Seeing a messy code snippet kinda takes away the desire to answer, you'll get much less feedback in your questions!)

Comment: i have another problem now..
i did as you said.. but now my output is

23235656191920204444

i.e. every integer two times is getting printed.WHY?

Comment: Oops, missed that. Your pattern must also include the newline! `fscanf` doesn't assume you have one block of data per line. See the edit above.

Comment: Add the newline to the pattern, it will fix your duplication problem. Try not to edit the original question so much, or the answers will stop making sense!

Comment: The first `fscanf` call doesn't consume the newline, so it's still in the stream. It's then interpreted as the character `%c` in the next pass, I guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3802/discussion-between-santiago-lezica-and-karan)

Comment: Note that using `\n` in the `fscanf` format string may be slightly misleading.  Any white-space character (including '`\n'`) matches zero or more white-space characters.  So adding the `\n` works for the given input -- but it would also work if the input were all on one line separated by spaces or tabs: `i 23 i 56 i 19 i 20 i 44`.  If you really want line-oriented input, use `fgets()` (*not* `gets()`) to read a line at a time into a string, then `sscanf()` to parse the string.  (All the `*scanf()` functions have problems with numeric overflow, though.)

Answer (score -1):

`a.activity` is uninitialized until `fscanf` returns the first time. While you are debugging, keep this in mind. Most debuggers will put a "cursor" on the first line which has not yet been executed; therefore, when the `fscanf` line is highlighted the first time, `a.activity` will not yet be initialized, and may have any value at all in it.